# Retrieve just the phone number data from a nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to retrieve data (just the phone number) from a nested JSON using Newtonsoft dll.
Json (request) looks something like this :

```
[{
    "name": "sam",
    "age": 19,
    "Gender" : "F",
    "Email" : "sam@test.com",
    ...
    "PhoneNumber" :{
        "CCode":"1",
        "Area": "123",
        "PhoneNum": "456-789",
        "PhoneExtn": ""
     }
    ...
}]
```

I have many more values in the [json](/questions/tagged/json), but I need only phone number, so creating a Custom Class with above properties and using <kbd>DeserializeObject</kbd> on the above JSON string is not an option. However, I did try the below options:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request);

var option1 = (string)jsonObj["PhoneNumber"]["CCode"];
var option2 = (string)jsonObj["PhoneNumber"][0]["CCode"];

//option3
 PhoneNumberModel phone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhoneNumberModel>(jsonObj["PhoneNumber"].ToObject<string>());

//option4 
PhoneNumberModel phone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhoneNumberModel>(jsonObj["PhoneNumber"][0].ToObject<string>());
```

Get these exceptions:

```
1. Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type for first three options
2. Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected for option 4.
```

I have tried many online solutions provided but none work. I am running out of options now.

Comment: You don't **have** to create properties for all json properties; just the ones you need...

Comment: @Kyle. Yes, this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the properties that you need.

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PhoneNumber")]
    public PhoneNumberModel { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumberModel
{
    public int CCode { get; set;}
    public int Area { get; set;}
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
    public string PhoneExtn { get; set; }
}

var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
var name = person.Name;
var phoneNumber = person.PhoneNumberModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)` API but sending the whole request to it? Something like this:

```
PhoneNumberModel phone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhoneNumberModel>(request);
```

Newtonsoft ignores the missing properties in the target class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `PhoneNumber` into your model like this:

```
PhoneNumberModel model =
    JArray.Parse(json)[0]
          .SelectToken("PhoneNumber")
          .ToObject<PhoneNumberModel>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/U21KfN